# Configure URL Redirection With Azure Active Directory

Tags: c#, azure, model-view-controller, azure-active-directory

I have Deployed a MVC Application that use ADD Login for authentication.

now I have problem to continue work on my localhost as I am redirected to the actual website, just after login in.

I can configure redirection in Azure portal, under app registration, but that requires me to change url everytime I want to do some work, and makes actual website not working for that time.

I won't to be able to run app on my local host, but keep the deployed one still working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but that requires me to change url everytime I want to do some work, and makes actual website not working for that time

If I understand you correctly, the `url` you mean the `Redirect URI` in the portal. If so, you don't need to change it every time, you could configure both of the Redirect URIs you need in the `Redirect URIs` list like below.

[image]

Then when you run your app in local, you just need to change the `redirect_uri` in the authorization URL when the user login. It will not affect the app in the cloud.

Sample(url encode for `http://localhost:3000`):

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id}/oauth2/authorize
?client_id=ef92a29b-b332-9d43-1341-23326315fa42
&response_type=id_token+token
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000
&state=12345
&nonce=678910
&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F
```